# How to compare 5 different arrays and creating a new array based on the number of the same values in each index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 5 different arrays such that:

```
A=[1,0,2,1,1]
B=[1,0,1,1,2]
C=[1,1,1,1,2]
D=[2,0,2,1,1]
E=[1,0,2,1,1]
```

the new array will be:

```
final_array=[1,0,2,1,1]
```

So simply, there are four "1" in the first element of the arrays so the first element of the new array will be "1", there are three "2" in the third element of the arrays so the third element of the new array will be "2", etc.

Can anyone help to write this piece of code?

Comment: np.unique(arr, return_counts=True, axis=0) would solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting the arrays into a 2D array and then taking the mode along the first axis:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[1, 0, 2, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [2, 0, 2, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1, 1]])
>>> arr
array([[1, 0, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 0, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 1, 1]])
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> stats.mode(arr, axis=0)
ModeResult(mode=array([[1, 0, 2, 1, 1]]), count=array([[4, 4, 3, 5, 3]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is `scipy.stats.mode`:

```
from scipy.stats import mode

out, _  = mode(np.array([A,B,C,D,E]),axis=0)
```